# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 9500 (com.schonell), pid 9500

Tags: android, video, exoplayer2.x, linphone-sdk

I'm getting this exact crash/error message from logcat for my Android app.

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 9500 (com.schonell), pid 9500
```

No more crash log details only this message showing. This happened every time when my video calling app end the calls and crash the app. Video call used Linphone for Audio and Google exoplayer for video showing.

I've no clue why this is happening.

Comment: hii . did you solve this issue?

Comment: Still I can't able to fix the issue. Most weird things is that there is no details error log. Hope someone can help.

Comment: I have the same error since move to androidx, any solution?

Comment: Hi @keno still didn't get any proper solution but you can try to update the NDK to latest version and that might help you because since I updated my NDK it stops this crashing. I don't know whether upgrade NDK fixed the error or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to the incorrect use of an AlertDialog. If so, try to minimize it by eliminating any Handler or Looper from inside

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a
`android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` registered in your Manifest.xml

I also had a similar problem after adding the `android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` in Manifest.
After removing it from the Manifest, the error disappeared.